# How to stop/play using html5 canvas?

Tags: animation, actionscript, html5-canvas

Hi I'm a beginner with html5 canvas. I try all the code I know on how to stop the music but it keeps playing even I click the play/pause button.

Code:

```
var comp = this;
var pause = "false";
//var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("pokemon.mp3");  
//var sound:Sound = new Sound();  
//var controller:SoundChannel; 

comp.push_btn.addEventListener("click", stopAnimate);

function stopAnimate()
{
    if(pause == "true")
    {
        comp.stop();
        //controller.stop();  
        pause = "false"
    }
    else
    {
        comp.play();
        //controller = sound.play(); 
        pause = "true";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isPause = false;

function soundControlling(){
    if(!isPause){
        isPause = true;
        myInstance.paused = true;
    }else{
      isPause = false;
      myInstance.paused = false;
    }
}

this.push_btn.addEventListner("click",soundControlling.bind(this));
```

Comment: Add some explanation